# androidで、ダウンロードした画像ファイルからURIを生成する方法は？

Tags: android

お世話になっております。

サーバーからダウンロードした画像データーのUriを取得しようと考えております。
ダウンロードした画像ファイルからuriを生成する場合はやはりどこかに保存するしかないので
しょうか？
現在の対応策としては一時キャッシュなどを作成し、ダウンロードした画像をそこに入れてから
Uriを生成し、アプリ終了時にキャッシュファイルを削除する流れにしようと考えているのですが
、皆様はダウンロードファイルをUriにする場合どのような方法をとられているのでしょうか？

ぜひ参考にさせて下さい。

Comment: 質問内容は「ダウンロードした画像ファイルのURIを生成する方法」でしょうか？

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。
そうです。ダウンロードした画像ファイルからURIを生成する方法です。